# MetaPost - How do I turn off 'end occured when if...' messages?

Tags: metapost

Consider the following code:

```
beginfig(1);

i:=0;

forever: 

    if odd i:
        show(i);
        exitif true;
    fi

    i:=i+1;
endfor

endfig;

end
```

When I run it, I get `(end occurred when if on line 13 was incomplete)`.

Is there is a way to turn these messages off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be a better way, but similarly to conditionals in TeX, one way is to ensure that `fi` is expanded before `exitif` is executed. So e.g.

```
beginfig(1);

i:=0;

forever: 

    if odd i:
        show(i);
        expandafter exitif expandafter true expandafter;
    fi

    i:=i+1;
endfor
endfig;

end
```

or

```
beginfig(1);

i:=0;

forever: 

    if odd i:
        show(i);
        scantokens "fi"
        exitif true;
    fi

    i:=i+1;
endfor
endfig;

end
```

In the second version, the `scantokens` hides the first `fi` when the condition is false, while it is executed when the condition is true and the second `fi` is skipped.

Comment: This works, but I wonder why I find no occurrence of `expandafter` in the MetaPost manual (version 2.00, June 1, 2019). Do you have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: @frougon As chapter B.1 says: "Certain other features from METAFONT are omitted entirely because they are of limited interest to the MetaPost users and/or would require long explanations.  All of these are documented in The METAFONTbook as explained in Appendix C.1."

Comment: But the short version is: expandafter works exactly the same as \expandafter in TeX, you just have to think about what a token is here.

Comment: This is very nice, thanks. So `def break = expandafter exitif expandafter true expandafter enddef;`  is all I need now.

Comment: @PatrikBak That version of break has to be followed by `fi` (or `else`) *directly*. Especially, it should never be used before `endfor`. (Otherwise you break out of the wrong loop)