# Why does this METAPOST primarydef damage the vardef that calls it?

Tags: metapost

METAPOST `cutbefore` and `cutafter` are not perfectly reliable in *where* they cut, if the path to be cut crosses the path where it must cut multiple times. To solve that' I've created two `primarydefs` (maxcutbefore and maxcutafter) that can be used just as cutbefore and cutafter, but that remove as much as possible. This works. This minimal example shows it:

```
primarydef inPath mycutafter cutPath =
  begingroup
  save resultPath; path resultPath;
  save tmpPath, checkPath; path tmpPath, checkPath;
  save aT;
  resultPath := inPath; % Algo: we return resultPath unless checkPath is an improvement
  forever:
    aT := arctime ((arclength resultPath)-1) of resultPath; % t where length is length minus 1bp
    checkPath := subpath( 0, aT) of resultPath;
    tmpPath := checkPath cutafter cutPath;
    if (arclength tmpPath) < (arclength checkPath):
      % we have actually cut the path further
      resultPath := tmpPath; % set current result value and try again
    else:
      % we did not cut the path further, we have our result
      exitif true;
    fi
  endfor;
  resultPath
  endgroup
enddef;

vardef TEST( expr inputConn, fromPicOutline, toPicOutline) =
  save resultConn, workingConn; path resultConn, workingConn;
  workingConn := inputConn;
%  if true:
    resultConn := (inputConn cutbefore fromPicOutline) mycutafter toPicOutline;
%  else:
%    show "HELLO";
%  fi
  resultConn
enddef;

path line, ca, cb;
ca := fullcircle scaled 2 shifted (-5,0);
cb := fullcircle scaled 2 shifted (5,0);
line := (-10,0)--(10,0);
line := TEST( line, ca, cb);
draw ca;
draw cb;
draw line;
```

As you can see, I'm using `mycutafter`. If you change that to `cutafter`, it also works, but the line is cut to the right of the right circle, not to the left.

But when I uncomment the if:--else:--fi lines, the vardef `TEST` fails with:

```
metapost log    > ! Extra 'else'.
metapost log    > TEST->...2)cutbefore(EXPR3))mycutafter(EXPR4);else
metapost log    >                                                   :show"HELLO";fi.resultConn...
metapost log    > <*> ...-10,0)--(10,0); line := TEST( line, ca, cb)
metapost log    >                                                   ; draw ca; draw cb; draw l...
```

But if I uncomment the lines and use the original `cutafter`, it also works. There must be something I do not understand regarding the grammar of METAFONT that makes my primarydef interfere with my vardef code. But what? And why?

Comment: Related(?): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536334/metapost-how-do-i-turn-off-end-occured-when-if-messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reduce the problem to a much simpler file:

```
tracingall;
if true:
  forever:
    if false:
    else:
      exitif true;
    fi
  endfor;
else:
fi
```

results in

> `! Extra else`

Why?

`exitif true` terminates the current loop *immediately*. Given that MetaPost is not parsing the file beforehand but picking up tokens at it goes, this means that the remaining part of the loop, including the *inner* `fi`, is never execute. So as far as MetaPost is concerned, the inner `if false` was never terminated by a `fi` so we are still in the `else:` block when the outer `else:` is seen. This of course is not allowed, leading to the error `Extra else`.

How can you fix that? As mentioned by Scott H. in a comment, you can use the same  tricks as in [MetaPost - How do I turn off 'end occured when if...' messages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536334/metapost-how-do-i-turn-off-end-occured-when-if-messages) to insert a `fi` before the `exitif` which is only seen if the `else` block is actually executed.

But the design of MetaPost actually anticipated such a need, that's why `exitif` accepts a condition: You can avoid the `if` by writing that break condition directly after `exitif`:

```
primarydef inPath mycutafter cutPath =
  begingroup
  save resultPath; path resultPath;
  save tmpPath, checkPath; path tmpPath, checkPath;
  save aT;
  resultPath := inPath; % Algo: we return resultPath unless checkPath is an improvement
  forever:
    aT := arctime ((arclength resultPath)-1) of resultPath; % t where length is length minus 1bp
    checkPath := subpath( 0, aT) of resultPath;
    tmpPath := checkPath cutafter cutPath;
    exitif length cuttings = 0;
    % if we reach this point we have actually cut the path further
    resultPath := tmpPath; % set current result value and try again
  endfor;
  resultPath
  endgroup
enddef;

vardef TEST( expr inputConn, fromPicOutline, toPicOutline) =
  save resultConn, workingConn; path resultConn, workingConn;
  workingConn := inputConn;
  if true:
    resultConn := (inputConn cutbefore fromPicOutline) mycutafter toPicOutline;
  else:
    show "HELLO";
  fi
  resultConn
enddef;

path line, ca, cb;
ca := fullcircle scaled 2 shifted (-5,0);
cb := fullcircle scaled 2 shifted (5,0);
line := (-10,0)--(10,0);

beginfig(0);
line := TEST( line, ca, cb);
draw ca;
draw cb;
draw line;
endfig;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It remains difficult to wrap your mind around this kind of 'inline macro expansion' if you have been doing functions for much of the last 20 years.